# How to create custom error handling in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-3.5

```
i = 0
numbers = ["1","1","1","1","1"]
while 0 == 0:
   print(numbers[i])
   i+=1
```

Once finished it would say out of index/range. How would I get it to say ran out of numbers instead of an error?

I think it's called error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle errors using try and except

```
try:
   print(numbers[i])
except Exception:
   print("ran out of numbers")
```

Replacing `Exception` with the one you are [receiving](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `while`, I would use `for`.

```
numbers = ["1","1","1","1","1"]
for n in numbers:
  print(n)
print("ran out of numbers")
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace tells you what exception to catch

```
>>> i = 0
>>> numbers = ["1","1","1","1","1"]
>>> while 0 == 0:
...    print(numbers[i])
...    i+=1
... 
1
1
1
1
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So add a try/except block

```
>>> i = 0
>>> numbers = ["1","1","1","1","1"]
>>> try:
...     while 0 == 0:
...         print(numbers[i])
...         i += 1
... except IndexError:
...     print("Ran out of numbers!")
... 
1
1
1
1
1
Ran out of numbers!
```

But please go through some of the excellent python tutorials out there. This will be a painful way to learn the language!

Comment: for completeness, you may want to `break` after the `print` statement to avoid infinite loop

Comment: @downshift - the try/except is outside of the while loop so there is no infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying your code, you can [raise a custom exception message](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) and then `break` to avoid the infinite loop:

```
i = 0
numbers = ["1","1","1","1","1"]
while 0 == 0:
   try:
      print(numbers[i])
      i+=1
   except IndexError:
      print('ran out of numbers')
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is always true, therefore it prints each element 0-4, then tries to print the 6th element, which does not exist - thus an out of index/range error.
Try using a "for" loop instead.  Psuedocode: for x in numbers print(numbers[x])

Comment: Maybe... but OP says he wants to tell the user he ran out of numbers, not that he wants to avoid running out of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try..except`. Instead of `0 == 0`, you can just use `True`:

```
i = 0
numbers = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

try:
    while True:
        print(numbers[i])
        i += 1
except IndexError:
    print("Run out of numbers")
```